# Linear Regression model (using Gradient Descent) does not converge on Boston Housing Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I've been trying to find out why my linear regression model performs poorly when compared to sklearn's linear regression model.

My linear regression model (update rules based on gradient descent)

```
w0 = 0
w1 = 0
alpha = 0.001
N = len(xTrain)
for i in range(1000):
  yPred = w0 + w1*xTrain
  w0 = w0 - (alpha/N)* sum(yPred - yTrain)
  w1 = w1 - (alpha/N)*sum((yPred - yTrain) * xTrain)
```

Code for plotting the values of x from the training set and the predicted values of y

```
#Scatter plot between x and y
plot.scatter(xTrain,yTrain, c='black')    
plot.plot(xTrain, w0+w1*xTrain, color='r')
plot.xlabel('Number of rooms')
plot.ylabel('Median value in 1000s')
plot.show()
```

I get the output as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvOfM.png

On running the same code using sklearn's inbuilt linear regression, I get this
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvOfM.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvTyq.png)

Can anyone help me where my model is going wrong? I have tried changing a number of iterations and learning rates, but there were no significant changes.

Here's the ipython notebook on colab if it helps: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1c3lWKkv2lJfZAc19LiDW7oTuYuacQ3nd

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a bigger learning rate such an 0.01. And it more times such as 500000 times. Then you will get a similar result. 
[image]

Or you can initialize the w1 with a bigger number such as 5.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any fixed rules to follow during initial weight initializations? Or is it just trial and error?